# Is the association of factory_girl a reference or created repeatedly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I am using mongoid in my rails app. Because it doesn't support fixtures, I use factory_girl instead. Then I build two models:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document

  field name, type: String
  validates :name, uniquess: true
end

class Post
  include Mongoid::Document

  belongs_to :user
end
```

Then I build two factories like belowing:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    name 'user'
  end
end

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :post1, class: 'Post' do
    user
  end
end

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :post2, class: 'Post' do
    user
  end
end
```

Just like above, creating an user with two posts, it is what I want.

I follow the thought of fixtures, that preparing all data before running test cases. I do it using following code:

```
Mongoid::default_client.database.drop
FactoryGirl.lint
```

However, it generates an error, due to repeatedly creating the user in the post factory not refering the previous definition of user factory:

```
rake aborted!
FactoryGirl::InvalidFactoryError: The following factories are invalid:

* user - 
message:
Validation of User failed.
summary:
The following errors were found: Name is already taken
resolution:
Try persisting the document with valid data or remove the validations. (Mongoid::Errors::Validations)/home/hello/workspace/scaffold/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/linter.rb:14:in `lint!'
/home/hello/workspace/scaffold/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/linter.rb:4:in `lint!'
/home/hello/workspace/scaffold/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl.rb:59:in `lint'
/home/hello/workspace/scaffold/test/test_helper.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
/home/hello/workspace/scaffold/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/home/hello/workspace/scaffold/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
/home/hello/workspace/scaffold/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/home/hello/workspace/scaffold/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/home/hello/workspace/scaffold/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:114:in `block (3 levels) in define'
/home/hello/workspace/scaffold/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:114:in `each'
/home/hello/workspace/scaffold/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:114:in `block (2 levels) in define'
/home/hello/workspace/scaffold/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:113:in `each'
/home/hello/workspace/scaffold/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:113:in `block in define'
/home/hello/workspace/scaffold/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:31:in `create_and_run_single_test'
/home/hello/workspace/scaffold/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:17:in `invoke_rake_task'
/home/hello/workspace/scaffold/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/test_unit/testing.rake:8:in `block in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => test:single
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: Are you wiping your database?

Comment: Yeah. This line do it: Mongoid::default_client.database.drop

Answer (score 0):

In User model you have a validation:

```
validates :name, uniquess: true
```

For generation uniq names via FactoryGirl you should use sequences:

```
sequence(:name) { |n| "person#{n}" }
```

Comment: I edited my question, now there are one user and two posts(belongs_to the same user)

Answer (score 0):

Define your `user` factory to emit unique names by using a generated sequence:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
    sequence :username do |n|
        "Name#{n}"
    end
    factory :user do
        name { generate :username }
    end
end
```

EDIT to reflect updated question:

Factories are not fixtures, they do not define a particular object, but a way to create a series of that.

To make a user with two or more posts - define a factory for `User` and `Post` then in your tests generate objects. No need for factory for each post, usually there's single factory for each model, to handle some specific cases there're ['traits'](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/remove-duplication-with-factorygirls-traits).

For example using rspec:

```
let(:user){ create :user }
let(:first_post_of_this_user) { create :post, user: user }
let(:second_post_of_same_user){ create :post, user: user }
```

or just in plain ruby:

```
user = FactoryGirl.create :user
posts = 2.times.map{ FactoryGirl.create :post, user: user }
```

Comment: I edited my question, now there are one user and two posts(belongs_to the same user)

Comment: see updated answer on how to make posts refer to same generated user

Comment: Thank you. This is what I confused, that I cannot find a place just to define all data, not a complex mode to organize them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an excellent gem for random create `name, email, number, phone`

[Faker](https://github.com/stympy/faker)

> While Faker generates data at random, returned values are not
>   guaranteed to be unique.

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    name {Faker::Name.name }
  end
end
```

Comment: I edited my question, now there are one user and two posts(belongs_to the same user)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the name validation, the problem is you don't want the factories to generate multiple users.

This is wrong... `class 'User`'... this is telling factory_girl to build a User object instead of a Post object.  Plus you don't need to define two identical factories.

What you mean to do is...

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :post, class: Post
end
```

and then...

```
user = create(:user)
post1 = create(:post, user: user)
post2 = create(:post, user: user)
```

Comment: Thank you. Maybe I am more customed to the mode of fixtures as a test newer.